# Custom time range for the posts_where filter

Tags: posts-where

I'm creating a function that displays the most viewed posts and would like to be able to show posts based on how old they are. Modifying the query is not really a problem. But since I can't pass any arguments to the function I can't modify the "-30 days" part.

```
function print_stuff($args) {
    add_filter( 'posts_where', 'filter_where');
    $posts = new WP_query($args);
    remove_filter( 'posts_where', 'filter_where' );
    // The loop
}

function filter_where($where = '') {
    $where .= " AND post_date > '" . date('Y-m-d', strtotime('-30 days')) . "'";
    return $where;
}
```

I guess I could store the value in the DB and then retrieve it, but that would feel ugly. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

You can set your own custom query vars in a query, then use that value to set a class variable that you later read in the filter:

```
class WPA69844_where {
    var $days;

    public function __construct(){
        add_action( 'parse_query', array( $this, 'parse_query' ) );
    }

    public function parse_query( $query ) {
        if( isset( $query->query_vars['my_days_var'] ) ):
            $this->days = $query->query_vars['my_days_var'];
            add_filter( 'posts_where', array( $this, 'filter_where' ) );
            add_filter( 'posts_selection', array( $this, 'remove_where' ) );
        endif;
    }

    public function filter_where($where = '') {
        $where .= " AND post_date > '" . date('Y-m-d', strtotime('-' . $this->days . ' days')) . "'";
        return $where;
    }

    public function remove_where() {
        remove_filter( 'posts_where', array( $this, 'filter_where' ) );
    }


}
$wpa69844_where = new WPA69844_where();
```

Then for your query:

```
$args = array( 'my_days_var' => 30 );
$posts = new WP_query( $args );
```

Comment: This is a very elegant solution. Thanks for sharing it.

Answer (score 1):

You can store the time range using some global/static/class variable & then retrieve it from there

or use filters (the concept wordpress is built on). Here is an example

```
function filter_where($where = '') {
    $time = apply_filters('custom_where_clause', '-30days');
    if(!$time)
        $time = '-30days';

    $where .= " AND post_date > '" . date('Y-m-d', strtotime($time)) . "'";
    return $where;
}

add_filter('custom_where_clause', 'custom_where_clause_logic');
function custom_where_clause_logic($time) {
    // put your logic here
    // make sure you return the value
}
```