# Use post__in and post__not_in together?

Tags: wp-query, get-posts

I'm trying to only show posts that a user hasn't seen, like this:

```
$exclude = array(1,2,3);
$include = array(3,4,5);
$args = array(
  'post_type'           => 'post',
  'post_status'         => 'publish',
  'posts_per_page'      => 30,
  'post__in'            => $include,
  'post__not_in'        => $exclude,
  'orderby'             => 'post__in',            
  'tax_query'           => array(
        'relation' => 'AND',
         array(
            'taxonomy'  => 'category',
            'field'     => 'slug',
            'terms'     => array($category_names),
            'operator'  => 'IN'
         ),
         array(
            'taxonomy'  => 'category',
            'field'     => 'ID',
            'terms'     => array($category_ids),
            'operator'  => 'NOT IN'
         )
  )
);
$posts = get_posts($args);
```

I'd expect this to return posts 4 and 5, but it returns 3, 4, and 5.

How do I set which gets preference between 'post_*in' and the 'post*_not_in' parameters?

I know that I could use array_diff() on the $exclude and $include variables, but the reality is more complicated than this question. I have many different arrays to compare against, and some of them are multidimensional. I'm also including and excluding certain taxonomies.

I also think it's easier for others to read if it's a WP_Query or $wpdb call, rather than lines and lines of PHP to end up with a query parameter.

Also, if array_diff equal an empty array, then the query actually returns posts, not nothing.

So perhaps the best way is a $wpdb call, or a way to use WP_Query's meta_query on the post ID field?

Comment: Could you please explain the complicated reality?

Comment: Updated to explain why I don't want to use array_diff if possible. I think a $wpdb approach might be best.

Comment: @DrewBaker I still do not understand a think. You say: _I have many different arrays to compare against, and some of them are multidimensional_ But to use `include` and `exclude` you have to pass a flat array of ids. So do you do some logic to _exctract_ two flat arrays from the different and multidimensional array? If so, you can actually run `array_diff` and if result is empty you can use an `if` and never run the query, `$posts = ! empty($diff) ? get_posts($args) : array();`

Comment: OK, I hear what you guys are saying. I'll use array_diff(). Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`post__in` and `post__not_in` are mutually exclusive.

> Note: you cannot combine post__in and post__not_in in the same query.
>
> http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query

As your question is written, the solution you reject-- that of using `array_diff`-- is the obvious answer.

If it is true that that solution won't work you will need a filter on `posts_where` (probably) that will provide the query logic you need. As you have not explained "the reality [that] is more complicated than this question" it is really not possible to offer a guess at what that logic might be.

But [here is an example of a `posts_where`](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/75389/21376) filter:

```
function smbd_cats_by_days ($where = '') {
    // global $days_limit; // if a variable
    // $days_limit = DAYS_LIMIT; // if a constant
    // $days_limit = get_option('days_limit',100);
    // you have to uncomment one of the above, 
    // depending on your choice of mechanisms
    $where .= " AND post_date < '" . date('y-m-d', strtotime("-{$days_limit} days")) . "'";
    return $where;
}
add_filter('posts_where', 'smbd_cats_by_days');
```

Based on the edit to the question and on this statement of intent:

> I'm trying to only show posts that a user hasn't seen...

Write the PHP to create an array of posts that the user has seen and exclude them with `post__not_in`. Your attempt to shove everything into the query is only complicating things.

> I also think it's easier for others to read if it's a WP_Query or
>   $wpdb call, rather than lines and lines of PHP to end up with a query
>   parameter.

By the time your write the filters and or SQL to include everything in the query it will not be more "readable" and it is questionable whether it would be more readable in the first place. You are trying to do this the hard way. `WP_Query` is not capable of complex logic and complex logic in SQl is hard to write and hard the read even on a good day.

Comment: or maybe a `posts_join` [http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/posts_join](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/posts_join)

Comment: Thanks, I get it. I'll use array_diff() then. Thanks. I up voted this answer as you worked hard to answer my bad question.

Answer (score 4):

Excude and include cannot be used together, this code is used in core, so or one or the other.

```
...
if ( ! empty($r['include']) ) {
  $incposts = wp_parse_id_list( $r['include'] );
  $r['posts_per_page'] = count($incposts);  // only the number of posts included
  $r['post__in'] = $incposts;
} elseif ( ! empty($r['exclude']) )
...
```

A $wpdb query is easy if the only arguments you need are only ones you posted.

This way is easy, but if you can't can explain why?

```
$exclude = array(1,2,3);
$include = array(3,4,5);
$args = array(
    'post_type'         => 'post',
    'post_status'       => 'publish',
    'posts_per_page'    => 30,
    'post__in'          => array_diff($include, $exclude),
)
$posts = get_posts($args);
```

Comment: *I know that I could use array_diff() on the $exclude and $include variables, but the reality is more complicated than this question. It must be done in the query.*

Comment: @s_ha_dum Sorry, my bad. Downvote the answer, I can't.

Comment: I updated the query to reflect all the parameters I'm using. A $wpdb query might be the best.

Comment: I was confused why my query wasn't working until I read the Codex about `WP_Query`. You can only use `post__in` or `post__not_in`. Not both of them together in the same query. I found this solution, and I must say this is a genius work-around solution.