# Date filter for post query not filtering results when variable outside the function

Tags: filters, date

I am working on the following code which should display the most popular posts that are X days old ($days = 7;)

(1) The main problem here is with my filter_where function. I want to pass the number of days from outside the function but it wont filter the results. The only way it filters them is to insert the variable inside the function. So, how can I use my variable from outsite the function?

(2) Another question I have is, In my get_topposts function, what happens after I return the query? Will the remove_filter and wp_reset_postdata still get executed or not? If not, how can I do so?

```
function get_topposts($days) {
//$ago = 7; // days
//$timestamp = time() - ($ago * 86400);

    function filter_where( $where = '' ) {
                   $where .= " AND post_date > '" . date('Y-m-d', strtotime('-'.$days.' days')) . "'";
                // $where .= " AND post_date > '" . date('Y-m-d', $timestamp) . "'";
                    return $where;
    }
    add_filter( 'posts_where', 'filter_where' );

     //$args = array(); 

    $the_query = new WP_Query( $args );
    return $the_query;
    remove_filter( 'posts_where', 'filter_where' );
    wp_reset_postdata();
}
```

EDITED: This is how it looks now after applying comments made by Milo

```
function filter_where( $where = '' ) {
//$days = apply_filters('custom_where_clause', '-30days');
//if(!$time)
            //$days = '-30days';
            // posts in the last 30 days
             //  $where .= " AND post_date > '" . date('Y-m-d', strtotime('-'.$days.' days')) . "'";
              $where .= " AND post_date > '" . date('Y-m-d', strtotime('-7days')) . "'";
                return $where;
}
//add_filter('custom_where_clause', 'get_topposts');

function get_topposts($posts) {
$the_query = get_transient('get_topposts');
if (empty($the_query)) {
    //$ago = 7; // days
    //$timestamp = time() - ($ago * 86400);
    //$days = 7;

    add_filter( 'posts_where', 'filter_where' );
    $args = array(
        'posts_per_page' => $posts,
        //'category_name' =>  'NAME OF CATEGORY',
        'post_status'=>'publish',
        'meta_key' => 'postviews',
        'orderby' => 'meta_value_num',
        'order' => 'DESC',
    ); 
    // The Query

    $the_query = new WP_Query( $args );
    set_transient('get_topposts', $the_query, 60*60*2);
    remove_filter( 'posts_where', 'filter_where' );
}
return $the_query;
}
```

Comment: [this question](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/69844/custom-time-range-for-the-posts-where-filter) has two answers for exactly this case. a couple of comments- don't nest functions in php, it's bad form. nothing after `return` gets executed, put that line last. `wp_reset_postdata` is unnecessary here, since you haven't yet touched the global `$post`.

Comment: Thank you for your comments. I got rid of the nested functions, removed `wp_reset_postdata`, and moved `return` to the end. Your solution on the question you mentioned looks very neat; however, I am looking for a simpler solution (if possible) that I can understand a little bit better.

Comment: Perhaps you could [Edit](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/posts/108280/edit) your question with your code changes.

Comment: ok, I just edited it to reflect the new changes.